# Parsing JSON output in Robot framework [Tried most options in the forum]

Tags: python, json, dictionary, robotframework, jsonparser

I have a JSON output like this:

```
{
   ":output":{
      "response":"{ \"ParentId\" : 125,  \"ParentKey\" : { \"key\" : \"9aqews-uwdguwdw8-9uw8\",                  \"identity\" : \"key_ID=674\" } }"
   }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the content of key, that is: **9aqews-uwdguwdw8-9uw8**

Here are somethings that tried:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------
 ${json_data}    Parse Json    ${output}
 Log    ${json_data["output"]["response"]}
 Log    ${json_data["output"]["response"][0][0:10]}
 ------------------------------------------------------

 ${json}=    Convert To Dictionary    ${values}
 ${j_keys}=    Get Dictionary Keys    ${json}
 Log  ${j_keys}
 ------------------------------------------------------

 ${values}=    Evaluate    json.loads($output)    json
 Log  ${values['output']['response'][1]}
 -----------------------------------------------------

 ${KeySP}=  Get Substring  ${values}  "key" ","
 Log  ${keySP}
 ------------------------------------------------------

  #${parkeydict}=  ${values['output']['response']}
  #${keyspacedict}=   ${parkeydict['ParentKey']}
  #Log  ${keyspacedict['key']}

 ------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried several other steps, possibilities and keywords,
The best I could parse is till "Log    ${json_data["output"]["response"]}" which returns data from 'response'.

It fails even if I convert to Dict and access the 'key', I think that further data after 'response' is completely stored as values.

Can someone help/guide me on how to capture the data in 'key' variable?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What does the keyword `Parse Json` come from?

Comment: It comes when you import HTTP Library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you're trying to use `['output']`, but the key is `:output`.

The second problem is that the value of the "response" key is not a dictionary, it's a string that looks like a dictionary. You must convert it to a dictionary before you try to pull values from it, assuming it is indeed an well-formed json dictionary and not just a string that might look like a dictionary.

This works for me on the exact data provided in the question:

```
${values}=      Evaluate      json.loads($output)
${response}=    Evaluate      json.loads($values[':output']['response'])
${key}=         set variable  ${response['ParentKey']['key']}

should be equal  ${key}  9aqews-uwdguwdw8-9uw8
```

Note: if you're using a version of robot that is older than 3.2 you'll need to include `json` as a final argument for the `Evaluate` command so that robot knows to import the module. Starting with version 3.2 and onward, modules used in the expression are automatically imported.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting, the actual code has ['output'] only. I did some debugging of the solution that you have given. We need to specify the name 'json' after evaluate. It'll give "failed: NameError: name 'json' is not defined" if we have not added it. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: _"We need to specify the name 'json' after evaluate."_ - that's only true for versions of robot older than 3.2. From the official documentation for the  `Evaluate` keyword: "Starting from Robot Framework 3.2, modules used in the expression are imported automatically"

Comment: Ah, I guess my org uses the older version! maybe that's why I couldn't figure this out!

Comment: {
  "output": {
    "ParentKey": {
      "key": "9b92e6638-c5f7a66c0cc1",
      "id": "uid=260"
    }
  }
}  Hi @Bryan How do we fetch keyspace for this output? Thank you!!!